# Return promise from Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have callable function in my Cloud Functions:

```
export const getUserByEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const email = data.email

  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
})
```

And I call it in my Angular application:

```
public getUserByEmail(email: string) {
  return this.cloudFunctions.httpsCallable('getUserByEmail')(email)
}

...

this.getUserByEmail(email)
```

How should I change my function to be able to use it like this:

```
this.getUserByEmail(email)
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

And return 500 from cloud function on error?

Comment: Are you saying that if getUserByEmail yields an error, that it doesn't propagate that error to the client?  If you return a rejected promise from the function, it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors), if you want your client (front-end) to receive errors sent from the Callable Cloud Function, you need to "return errors from a callable by throwing (or returning a Promise rejected with) an instance of [`functions.https.HttpsError`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError)".

So, in your Cloud Function you need to throw an `HttpsError`, as shown below.  In this example we treat the case of a `user-not-found` error thrown by the Admin SDK and, in turn we throw an `HttpsError` with a `not-found` code.

See other possibilities for the `HttpsError` codes in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError) (table "Parameter"), and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors) for the Admin Authentication API errors codes.

```
export const getUserByEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const email = data.email

  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
  .catch(error => {   //Catching the error thrown by the Admin SDK

    if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {  

        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(  //throwing the HttpsError
                'not-found',
                'User with email (' + email + ') was not found!'
             );

    } else if (error.code === 'auth/...') {
        //Possibly manage other Admin Authentication API errors codes
    } else  {
        //...
    }

  })
})
```

And then, in your front-end, you do as follows (again, based on the doc, see the specific [section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client)):

```
this.getUserByEmail(email)
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(error => {
    var code = error.code;
    var message = error.message;
    console.log(code + '/' + message);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have something else to do (that might cause error) before returning the user data in the `https callable function`, you can do like this:

```
export const getUserByEmail = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const email = data.email

    // Return your own promise.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       try {
          // Do other stuff there might cause error.
       } catch (error) {
          // Reject if error.
          // But you might need to throw the HttpsError again if the client
          // can only get INTERNAL as error message.
          return reject(error);
       };
    
       return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
         .then((data) => {
            // Remember to resolve the promise, or else you may get an unexpected 
            // error, such as timeout or even an irrelevant CORS error.
            resolve(data);
         }
         .catch((error) => {
            // Follow @Renaud's idea in his answer.
         });

    });
});
```